# DHCP Offer already sent to my local IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp, dhcp-server

I entered these commands into Terminal to release my current local IP address and allocate a new one:

```
sudo ipconfig set en0 BOOTP
sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP
```

This is the screenshot of DHCP packets in Wireshark:

[image]

According to the book I am reading, the DHCP Offer message should be broadcasted to 255.255.255.255. That is not the case and I am confused how the router already knows my address, before it even entitled me one. 192.168.1.5 is indeed my old address. Does it store my MAC address and maps it to the old IP address it gave me? Is it possible to force the router (actually any DHCP server) to give me a new, different IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the DHCP server gets your MAC address from the DHCP request. It can include the offered IP-address in the reply packet's IP header (as well as in the DHCP payload) since it is only the MAC address that actually gets the delivery to the right destination.

Update (WIkipedia)

> When a DHCP server receives a DHCPDISCOVER message from a client, which is an IP address lease request, the server reserves an IP address for the client and makes a lease offer by sending a DHCPOFFER message to the client. This message contains the client's MAC address, the IP address that the server is offering, the subnet mask, the lease duration, and the IP address of the DHCP server making the offer.

### Request

Heres a request (DHCP DISCOVER) from the [Wireshark Samples](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures)

[image]

Note that it comes from 00:0b:82:01:fc:42 and goes to ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff (broadcast address)

Note also that [relevant RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt) says

> 1. The client broadcasts a DHCPDISCOVER message on its local physical
>        subnet.  The **DHCPDISCOVER message MAY include options that suggest
>        values for the network address** and lease duration.  BOOTP relay
>        agents may pass the message on to DHCP servers not on the same
>        physical subnet.

The client can ask the DHCP server if it can please, pretty please, with cherries on top, be allocated the IP-address it used yesterday before you turned it off. The DHCP server may consider allowing this if that address has not been allocated to another client.

### Reply

Heres the reply (DHCP OFFER)

[image]

Note the source is 00:08:74:AD:F1:9B and the destination is 00:0b:82:01:fc:42

Since this is all LAN-local, the contents of the address fields in the IP header are irrelevant. It is only the address fields in the Ethernet header that are used in getting the packet to where it needs to go.

Comment: thanks, but the part that I don't get, is how DHCP server sends Offer directly to 192.168.1.5. It doesn't know what my address is, because it hasn't entitled me one yet. It should send to 255.255.255.25,5 because I haven't accepted the new IP yet.  See the third packet destination in the image.

Comment: @sanjihan. The DHCP server knows the client's MAC address. Thats all that is needed to address the reply. You don't need or use IP-addresses at the network layer.

Comment: Than how did it come up with 192.168.1.5 as the destination, if it looked only at MACs?

Comment: @sanjihan: The DHCP server got that IP address from the next available number in its DHCP pool, or from its list of reservations or from the DHCP request. That is the whole point of DHCP, the server allocates an IP address to the client and sends it that information.  --- Are you CERTAIN you fully understand the difference in usage of MAC-addresses and IP-addresses?

Comment: @sanjihan: Heres where you are confused, you say *" I don't get, is how DHCP server sends Offer directly to 192.168.1.5"* -- The server does not do that (despite appearances). What the server actually does its send the offer to (something like) 00:0b:82:01:fc:42 - not to 192.168.1.5.  -- recall how addressing works in an Ethernet LAN!

Comment: certainly not, I have only made it to the network layer so far :D Thanks for clarifying things out, man. So if I were not behind a home router, would the DHCP Offer indeed be broadcasted to 255.255.255.255 (as the textbook implies)?